# How can I bisect a sphere twice

Tags: mesh

How can I cut a sphere in half twice?
I have been able to use the bisect tool to cut a sphere in half.
However, it will not allow me to cut one of the half spheres again.
I am ulimately looking to create a visor for the helmet of a knight mesh.

Thanks

Comment: Did you unselect the cut created by Bisect when first time cutting? Bisect will act on selected edges/faces, so if the sphere isn't fully selected, the result may be not as expected.